# How can I use a different name for a contact's card and their e-mail address in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, contacts, google-contacts, gmail-contacts

I have an Android phone, and my gmail contacts are automatically synced to it.

My phone is in Hebrew, and since most of my contacts are written in Hebrew I changed the ones in my gmail address book to be in Hebrew, so I would have a consistent name on my phone.

The problem is that now when I send an e-mail, the *name* of the contact is in Hebrew, which I don't like because it appears as junk on some computers.  Besides that, it appears very newbie-ish to me :-)

Is there any way to set some sort of display name for e-mail that is different from the name on the contact card?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 'File as' field for the Hebrew name

This name appears in the contacts list, and allows to search for it from the contacts pane (in the web version - the android version might behave differently).

A small problem is that the email completion in the compose window is based on the real name, and no

Comment: The File-as field is also what appears in the To field, not the contact name.

Comment: Just saw what you mean - If you click the 'email' button from the contact page you will have the address with the 'file as' name. If you select the address from the compose new mail (using auto complete, or from the 'choose contacts' dialog you will get the actual name.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/83927) greasmonkey script may be of help. I have not tested it though and you might have to change it a little bit to make it do what you want..